# Error Compiling Program in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, vsto, visual-studio-2008-sp1, compiler-errors

So I have never seen this issue before and don't know where to begin troubleshooting the issue.

```
Cannot register assembly "obj\Debug\MyProject.Vsto.dll".
Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)
```

Where do I start to troubleshoot this?

I should mention this is a VS2008 environment with VS2008 SP1 and this solution is:
1. A VSTO Excel 2007 Project (C#)
2. A Data Access / Service Layer DLL (C#)
3. An MbUnit test project for #2 (C#)

**UPDATE:**
I should add this did work fine for several months. The only thing that I have changed in the last week or so is I have started working on the code via Team Foundation Server (TFS).

**UPDATE 2:**
Deleting the `.suo` file worked for a little while. Now I'm getting same error again.... hmmm. Guess I'll close the project delete the `.suo` again.

**UPDATE 3:**
VS2008 will allow me to compile the solution once. The second time I try I get the error.
If I exit, delete the `.suo` file, and reopen I can compile one time again. Any thoughts to the cause? Is this an VS2008 SP1 thing?

For the bounty I'm looking for the permanent solution.

Comment: Answer auto-selected ... what the ? I ended up calling Microsoft will post the solution (when I have it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just FYI ... that looks like a CLR HRESULT (the 13 in the middle indicates that).
Acording to this blog post:[A lot of HRESULT codes...](http://blogs.msdn.com/eldar/archive/2007/04/03/a-lot-of-hresult-codes.aspx) That specific HRESULT is
SECURITY_E_INCOMPATIBLE_SHARE  0x80131401 -2146233343

Most likely some errant process is holding an open handle on the assembly and preventing the compiler from laying down a new one.   Given update #3 that process is probably devenv.exe ... which is unhelpful in narrowing it down, however it could be some background process which shuts down with VS (such as the debugger hosting process).

Assuming something is holding on the file ... to debug this type of thing the first step is to open procexp.exe from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) toolset.  In it you can use Find to determine which process has a handle open to the file.  I'd expect it to show a handle open within devenv.exe when you hit this issue.

From within procexp you can do the highly dangerous thing of closing the handle.  After that try the steps again without shutting down. If the problem doesn't repro then you know the handle you closed was the cause of the problem.  If anything else happens well ... that 'highly dangerous' step was likely the cause.

If you know what process has the open handle then you need to see if you can prevent it from hitting the apparent leak of the handle.  I would check the project settings ... including the debug ones for anything that copies the files.  If there is a debugger setting called VSHosting process ... turn that off.

Good luck.

Comment: If I don't delete the .suo file I cannot recompile.... even after a reboot. Does that sound like a process thing? I'm willing to try anything at this point. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Something written to the suo file could be triggering a leaked handled on restart.  [Or my theory on the cause could just be wrong.] I hope trying this out lead to something helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I did some Googling and found [this post on MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/214c997b-5618-4f4e-bdca-2ae7357bf988/) which may (or may not) prove useful to you.

It mentions a few Windows Updates patches that should be installed (if you're on Vista) as well as a workaround if you're on XP.  Although the post is referring to problems with Silverlight... the error is the same, so maybe?

Good luck!

Comment: I stumbled upon that same post but guess I didn't read down far enough. Not sure what caused the issue but getting rid of the .suo file worked. Resetting the settings from the Import/Export menu option in VS2008 did nothing. Thanks, Z. Anyone want to take a stab at what was actually happening here?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen that exact error, but similar errors can occur if there's another copy of the DLL that gets loaded from a different location.

I'd do a search to see if there's any other copies of that DLL lying around

```
dir MyProject.*.dll /s
```

Comment: How does erasing a .suo file resolve that (see my comment to Zemm)? I guess I will try this if the error comes up again. +1

Answer (score 1):

So it creates the dll but doesn't like to use it afterward?  If that's the case, have you tried to open the dlls in Reflector to see what differences there might be between the first and second compilation?

Another thought - have you tried a clean/rebuild after the first successful build?  Are you updating the version numbers on each compile?  I'm wondering if an outdated file is being referenced, but updated after the first compile.  At which point the references don't match the expected ones.

Another random thought - the .suo file generally contains info related to your individual machine.  Something related to the compilation shouldn't be saved in that file - it should go to the .sln instead.  It would seem odd that the .suo is the root cause...

Answer (score 1):

seems that you develop an ms - office extension. Then you should install the latest **COM Shim Wizard**. Download for VS2008 is [*here*](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3e43bf08-5008-4bb6-aa85-93c1d902470e&displaylang=en).

Managed Office extensions should be isolated from each other. [*This article on MSDN*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159894.aspx#odc_office_com_shim_wizards_howwizardworks) explains why and how.

I assume that your .dll is not isolated, and therefore your get that "Security-share-error":

> **Isolation.** If you do not use a
>   standard COM shim (such as the Visual
>   Studio Tools for Office loader) or
>   provide your own custom COM shim, your
>   extension DLL loads into the default
>   application domain along with all
>   other un-shimmed extensions. All DLLs
>   running in the same application domain
>   are vulnerable to potential damage
>   caused by any other DLL in the same
>   application domain. Also, any
>   un-shimmed add-in that crashes in a
>   host application disables all other
>   un-shimmed add-ins for that
>   application.

Developing office extensions looks so simple at the beginning, but then ....

Thomas

Comment: +1... this sounds good. Need a few hours to play with this... I'll get back to you. Thanks

Comment: oh, Any thoughts on why this affects me but not another developer working on same piece of code? And it worked fine for me for a few months.

Comment: Is it possible that you use Vista and the other developers use XP? Because on Vista I also had to install KB943729. This is an optional update which fixes Group Policy Preferences. Until now I didn't understand which effect this can have on .NET ...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/214c997b-5618-4f4e-bdca-2ae7357bf988/) which seems to highlight some similars issues.

how to troubleshoot? I would say first check that if your application could generate this kind of error message. Then checked if the libraries or system your software relies on could be faulty (then ask for support or community support).

Good luck.

Comment: I mean the users of the libraries/application/system may share information. I see that as a community of people share a same interest.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little outside my area but I did find the following [link which suggests that you are encountering a known defect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=95157) with .net 2.0.

I copied the following from the suggested work-around from microsoft:

> The problem will occur when marshaling
>   an object by value between two
>   appdomains in the same process where
>   the type of the instance is generic,
>   the generic template type is defined
>   in mscorlib, one or more of its
>   instantiating types is not defined in
>   mscorlib and multi-domain loader
>   optimization has been enabled in one
>   domain but not the other.
>
> Unfortunately this bug was discovered
>   too late and didn't make the bar for
>   the V2.0 product. There are some
>   workarounds however:
>
> This bug is specific to an optimized
>   version of the in-process,
>   cross-appdomain remoting channel and
>   therefore can be avoided by switching
>   this optimization off for the process.
>   This can be achieved either by setting
>   the the following environment variable
>   in the command window where the test
>   will be executed:
>
> ```
> set complus_UseNewCrossDomainRemoting=0
> ```
>
> Or by setting the
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft.NETFramework\UseNewCrossDomainRemoting
>   registry value (a DWORD) to 0 (or the
>   version in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE).
>
> These are a bit heavyweight, but it's
>   also possible to fool the optimized
>   path into avoiding just the specific
>   call that transfers the problematic
>   object. To do this add a dummy out
>   parameter to the call (for various
>   technical reasons the optimized path
>   doesn't implement out parameters yet).
>
> You can also avoid using an mscorlib
>   defined generic type. In the repro
>   case presented this is simple enough
>   since you can just subtype List:
>
> ```
> [Serializable]
> public class MyList<T> : List<T>
> {
> }
> ```
>
> (Just replace all uses of List with
>   MyList).
>
> Finally, the problem shouldn't occur
>   if both appdomains are using the
>   multi-domain optimization. You can't
>   set the default domain's loader
>   optimization after you're already
>   running it but you can either set it
>   externally (I believe via the
>   unmanaged hosting API or a config
>   file, though I'm not an expert in
>   either, sorry) or by creating a new
>   domain (with multi-domain opt) within
>   your code and transferring control to
>   it (via a call on an MBRO object in
>   that domain).

Sorry if you've already found this article in your searching but I didn't see it offered here as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're not messing with the system time are you? Doing that can mess up your assemblies.

Comment: Nope, not messing with the system time.